# relaunch the iphone app by AppDelegate programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, appdelegate

I'm new in iPhone, I created application that is started with UITabbarController with 4 items using AppDelegate. through the app I opened some views and I want to relaunch the AppDelegate again by using a code like:

```
[appdelegate presentModalViewController:myNavController animated:YES];
```

is this possible?

this is in my AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    MaktabatyTableViewController *own = [[MaktabatyTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    UINavigationController *ownNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:own];
    [array addObject:ownNavController];

    NewestTableViewController *newest = [[NewestTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    UINavigationController *newestNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newest] ;
    [array addObject:newestNavController];

    MostBuyTableViewController *mostbuy = [[MostBuyTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    UINavigationController *mostbuyNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mostbuy];
    [array addObject:mostbuyNavController];

    FreeBooksTableViewController *free = [[FreeBooksTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    UINavigationController *freeNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:free];
    [array addObject:freeNavController];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = array;

    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES; 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The straight answer to your question is "no, you can't"...but what is it you really want to accomplish?  For example, if it's just setting all the navigation controllers to their original root controllers, that's not so difficult.

Comment: may be, could you show me an example code to do this please ?

Comment: Perhaps you could tell me first whether that's what you really want.  Code without specifications is usually a bad idea.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this..

A login screen which is a simple view with login fields, upon login, this screen is of no use. And the main app is based on tab bar.

And a Logout screen or A screen showing after user signed out.

I had this requirement in one of my app, so i made a sample template. May be it helps you checkout [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58723521/TabBar.zip).